# Why is [el] showing undefined?

Tags: javascript, express, web-scraping, undefined, puppeteer

I am trying to do scraping using puppeteer.

```js
app.get("/info", async (req, res) => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQonuvvoXko&t=2s')

    // console.log(el)

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="description"]/yt-formatted-string')
    const text = await el.getProperty('textContent')
    const description = text.toString();

    // var descArr = description.split('/PC([^;]+)\n/')
    // const descText = /News([^;]+)\n/.exec(description)[1];
    browser.close()
    console.log(description);
    res.send(description)

    // console.log(text.toString())    
})
```

I am getting the following error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined

**Edit:** 
I have checked if my page and DOM is loaded successfully with these...

```js
page.on('load', () => console.log('page loaded', page.url()))
page.on('domcontentloaded' , () => console.log('dom loaded'))
```

Comment: el is array and Array don't have any property named ```getProperty```

Comment: It has. It's working fine for other websites.

Comment: forking a browser, loading the page, scraping the dom, closing a browser is going to vastly slower than using the youtube api (which is free)

Comment: el isn't an array, though, is it? It gets the first element of the array returned by `$x`.  But, if those elements are not on the page and the array for `$x` is empty, `el` will be undefined

Comment: Yes I understand that @LawrenceCherone. I am just trying out this method too.

Comment: You are right @GarrGodfrey. el isn't an array. It's an XPath variable. That's why you have access to getProperty

Comment: Also, the element IS present in that page because I am directly copying the Xpath from the DOM of that page. @GarrGodfrey

Comment: @MayukhDasgupta it might be present *eventually*, but probably only after the page has done additional rendering

Comment: That's a good point. Then what should I do about it? I am already awaiting that functionality. @GarrGodfrey

Comment: I don't know when `page.goto` completes, exactly. My guess is around the time the DOM `ready` event happens.  You probably need to put in some kind of loop or timer to repeatedly check until the element is present.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```js
const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="description"]/yt-formatted-string');
```

with

```js
const el = await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="description"]/yt-formatted-string');
```

Also, it seems the

```js
const description = text.toString();
```

should be:

```js
const description = await text.jsonValue();
```

Comment: using only el won't give me the getProperty method later and the description thing works fine.

Comment: @MayukhDasgupta It will: `page.$x()` returns an array of element handles, while `page.waitForXPath()` returns an element handle itself. And it waits for the element to appear.

Comment: I checked. Replacing [el] with el doesn't give me the getProperty method. @vsemozhebuty

Comment: @MayukhDasgupta Did you also replace `page.$x()` with `page.waitForXPath()`?

Comment: Yes I did that before only

Comment: @MayukhDasgupta Sorry, I cannot understand how this can happen. By the docs, `page.waitForXPath()` returns element handle that has `.getProperty()` method.